# extjs - rowedit - render a column to be blank

Tags: extjs, roweditor

I have 3 columns in a grid and I am using a row editor.

When the user clicks on the row, I want 2 of the 3 columns to be editable, and blank out the value in the 3rd column so that the value in the 3rd column is not visible.

How can that be done?

Below is the skeleton code that I have:

```
var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
                    clicksToEdit: 1,
                    pluginId: 'rowEditing'
                 });

tree.getPlugin('rowEditing').on('beforeedit', function(plugin, e) {
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `editor:{xtype:'hiddenfield'}`?

Comment: the value in the 3rd column should be visible when the roweditor is NOT active, but when the roweditor is active, then disable the roweditor

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I understood from your original post. But you didn't answer my question.

Comment: ExtJS replaces the standard renderer with the editor renderer, whenever you try to edit a row. The editor renderer will render a `hiddenfield` into the cell, which is not visible - and the standard renderer isn't visible as well, so it should look exactly as you need it.

Comment: thanks for pointing out that there is a actually a editor renderer that replaces the standard renderer.  That made me realize that i should add an editor to the column that is a blank label and that worked.

Comment: editor : {
             xtype : 'label'
         }